# undefined method `signup_path' for invitations( Still cant send beta invites )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

For the last days , I am trying to apply  a beta invite system. I followed railcasts lesson 124. And I customised it for my users .

My routes.rb

```
resources :invitations, only: [:new, :create]
match '/signup/:invitation_token',  to: 'users#new'
```

Invitation model :

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :new, :recipient_email, :user_id, :sent_at, :token

  belongs_to :user
    has_one :recipient, :class_name => 'User'

    validates_presence_of :recipient_email
    validate :recipient_is_not_registered
    validate :user_has_invitations, :if => :user

    before_create :generate_token
    before_create :decrement_user_count, :if => :user

    private

    def recipient_is_not_registered
        errors.add :recipient_email, 'zaten siteye üye' if User.find_by_email(recipient_email)
    end

    def user_has_invitations
        unless user.invitation_limit > 0
            errors.add_to_base 'Siteye davetiyeniz kalmamıştır.'
        end
    end

    def generate_token
        self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    end

    def decrement_user_count
        user.decrement! :invitation_limit
    end
end
```

Invitations_controller :

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @invitation = Invitation.new
    end

    def create
        @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
        @invitation.user = current_user
        if @invitation.save
            if signed_in?
                Mailer.deliver_invitation(@invitation, signup_path(@invitation.token))
                flash[:notice] = "Teşekkürler,davetiniz gönderildi."
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                flash[:notice] = "Teşekkürler,sizi almaya hazır olduğumuzda bildireceğiz."
                redirect_to root_path
            end
        else
    render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

. 
This is my mailer.rb:

```
def invitation(invitation, signup_url)
  subject    'Siteye Davet'
  recipients invitation.recipient_email
  from       'foo@example.com'
  body       :invitation => invitation, :signup_url => signup_path
  invitation.update_attribute(:sent_at, Time.now)
end
```

When I sent an invitation , my log file shows :

```
 INSERT INTO "invitations" ("created_at", "recipient_email", "sent_at", "token", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jul 2012 21:55:13 UTC +00:00], ["recipient_email", "neveryt@gmail.com"], ["sent_at", nil], ["token", "c29e2dcc22c033a1e975f5755795db9f2a8fd5c2"], ["updated_at", Wed, 04 Jul 2012 21:55:13 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (131.3ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 208ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `signup_path' for #<InvitationsController:0x000000044ef508>):
```

I can understand i must change the signup_url's. But I cant find the correct way.How can i fix the invitation create action?

Comment: I don't see signup_path actually defined anywhere, are you missing some source you could add to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `match` statement in your `routes.rb` to this:

```
match '/signup/:invitation_token',  to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
```

This will inform Rails that `signup_path` is the name for the matched route linking to `/signup/:invitation_token`.

Comment: I changed my route like that. I pasted my debugger below.

Comment: If this is the correct answer to your question, you should mark it as the correct answer. If it led to another question, you should post the new question separately, so that more people will see it/potentially answer it.

Comment: No still , I cant send invites.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is different, which makes this a different question.

Comment: Hmmm I posted my debugger hash. It shows the page without any problem now. But when i check email there is no mail, Is it because of I am using my localhost?

Comment: Make a new question of that, since I have no idea and no one else will read this question.

Comment: Should also add that this match line now requires `, via: [:get, :post] ` on the end of it.